# Insert into a table based on other two table values; SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

Can someone guide me on how to proceed to get the required output without using Contains condition

[image]

I have tried with Unpivot , Case statement and with Contains condition.But couldn't achieve the required output.

Comment: And where is your sql query which you tried?

Comment: If possible, get the table definitions changed. When you want to compute or query on multiple values, such that they're the same "type" of value, they ought to be stored in a *single* column. So base table 1 should have three columns `(Number,AA,Thing)` and store 4 rows for each number. `Thing` should contain the *data* that has currently ended up being embedded in the column names. Same for base table 2 and the `MMx` columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desired result using `CASE`:

```
SELECT
    t1.Number,
    [First] =   
        CASE 
            WHEN t1.AAA >= 5 THEN 'Yes'
            WHEN t1.AAB >= 5 THEN 'Yes'
            WHEN t1.AAC >= 5 THEN 'Yes'
            WHEN t1.AAD >= 5 THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
        END,
    [Second] = 
        CASE 
            WHEN t2.MMP >= 15 THEN 'Yes'
            WHEN t2.MMQ >= 15 THEN 'Yes'
            WHEN t2.MMA >= 15 THEN 'Yes'
            WHEN t2.MMC >= 15 THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
        END
FROM BaseTable1 t1
INNER JOIN BaseTable2 t2
    ON t2.Number = t1.Number
```

*Your's is not a good design. I suggest you normalize your data such that it'll be `BaseTable(Number, Col, Value)`*.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `CASE` expressions:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE(N INT, AAA MONEY, AAB MONEY, AAC MONEY, AAD MONEY)
DECLARE @t2 TABLE(N INT, MMP MONEY, MMQ MONEY, MMA MONEY, MMC MONEY)

INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES
(561, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5),
(562, 3.5, 4, 3.6, 3)

INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES
(561, 10, 10, 13, 15),
(562, 12, 10, 9, 14)

SELECT t1.N, 
       CASE WHEN t1.AAA >= 5 OR t1.AAB >= 5 OR t1.AAC >= 5 OR t1.AAD >= 5 
            THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS First,
       CASE WHEN t2.MMP >= 15 OR t2.MMQ >= 15 OR t2.MMA >= 15 OR t2.MMC >= 15 
            THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Second
FROM @t1 t1
JOIN @t2 t2 ON t1.N = t2.N
```

Output:

```
N   First   Second
561 Y       Y
562 N       N
```